# Detecting username in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I need to run a cmd that will create my home folder within a docker container. So, if my username in my linux box is josecz then I could use it from within a Dockerfile to run a cmd like:

RUN mkdir /home/${GetMyUsername}

and get the folder  /home/josecz  after the Dockerfile is processed.

Comment: This is not possible. The docker-process is isolated from the other OS processes. We could, however, use [`ARG`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg) to demand the value at image build time.

Comment: If the user in your developer laptop is Joe,  you need a container (running) that has a folder /home/joe ?

Comment: I need to create that folder within the container. Not by sharing folders

Comment: This usually isn't a best practice; you shouldn't have to recompile your image just because you're running it on a different host or as a different user.  It's fine to pick a fixed name (something like `/app` or `/data`).

Comment: I believe the exception to this case is when the docker container needs to run graphics as in this case it will be needed to get permissions to access the video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way just as commented by folks: use ARG, next gives you a workable minimal example:

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM alpine:3.14.0

ARG GetMyUsername

RUN echo ${GetMyUsername}
RUN mkdir -p /home/${GetMyUsername}
```

**Execution:**

```
cake@cake:~/3$ docker build --build-arg GetMyUsername=`whoami` -t abc:1 . --no-cache
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/4 : FROM alpine:3.14.0
 ---> d4ff818577bc
Step 2/4 : ARG GetMyUsername
 ---> Running in 4d87a0970dbd
Removing intermediate container 4d87a0970dbd
 ---> 8b67912b3788
Step 3/4 : RUN echo ${GetMyUsername}
 ---> Running in 2d68a7e93715
cake
Removing intermediate container 2d68a7e93715
 ---> 100428a1c526
Step 4/4 : RUN mkdir -p /home/${GetMyUsername}
 ---> Running in 938d10336daa
Removing intermediate container 938d10336daa
 ---> 939729b76f09
Successfully built 939729b76f09
Successfully tagged abc:1
```

**Explaination:**

When `docker build`, you could use `whoami` to get the username who run the `docker build`, then pass to args `GetMyUsername`. Then, in `Dockerfile`, you could use `${GetMyUsername}` to get the value.